# Send email of many rows in google sheet based on value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a tab called "Drivers" that has "Driver names" in column B, "Route numbers" in Column F and "Driver Emails" Column R.

I have another tab called "Routes" that shows all the customers that are in each route and they are sorted by route number from column K to S.

I would like to send a custom list of the customers to each driver according to their route number.

Any idea how I could get that done, I have very small knowledge of the google scripts, I've done basic stuff my can't even get an idea of a starting point

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Email Customer Names to Drivers**

Consider this a starting point as I have not even attempted to debug it.  However, it you will provide data as csv I'll be glad to do so.  Notice I did not ask for nor do I want a link to your spreadsheet.  Your redacted data file will be just fine.  You can post it in your question just like code.  Anything you don't want public should be redacted.  It would also be helpful to have images of your spreadsheets.

```
function sendCustomerlistToDrivers() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Driver');
  var dsr=2;//drivers starting row
  var drg=dsh.getRange(dsr,1,dsh.getLastRow()-dsr+1,dsh.getLastColumn());
  var dv=drg.getValues();
  var rsh=ss.getSheetByName('Routes');
  var rsr=2;//routes starting row
  var rsc=11;//routes starting col
  var rrg=rsh.getRange(rsr,rsc,rsh.getLastRow()-rsr+1,rsh.getLastColumn()-rsc+1);
  var rv=rrg.getValues();
  var rhA=rsh.getRange(rsr-1,rsc,1,rsh.getLastColumn()-rsc+1).getValues()[0];//assume header is one less than starting row
  var rcols={};
  rhA.forEach(function(h,i){rcols[h]=i+rsc;});
  dv.forEach(function(r,i){
    var driverEmail=r[17];//R
    var driverRoute=r[5];//F
    var driverName=r[1];//B
    var custNames=rsh.getRange(rsr,rcols[driverRoute],rsh.getLastRow()-rsr+1,1).getValues().map(function(){return r[0];}).filter(function(e){return e;}).join('\n');
    var msg=Utilities.formatString('\nRoute Number: %s\nCustomer Names: %s', driverRoute,custNames);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(driverEmail, 'Customer Names', msg)
  });
}
```